# Tomcat Embed Not Working in pom.xml (SpringBoot 3.0.0 M3)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm following a Udemy Course on learning SpringBoot, but I can't seem to get one of the dependencies installed. The tutorial asks to import a Tomcat dependency into pom.xml (in order to utilize JSP pages from resources), but after trying to import it:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId> <!-- Error comes from here -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error on the commented line.

```
Dependency 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:10.0.21' not found
```

What am I missing? I'm using IntelliJ, Java 18.0.1.1, and here is my pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-first-web-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-first-web-app</name>
    <description>My first SpringBoot web application from the Udemy Course</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I will edit this to provide any additional information needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove the `<repositories>` section in pom.xml and try to build. Looks like the jar is not available in Spring repository. It will get downloaded from maven central if none mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to have done exactly what you've said. Now I just gotta figure out why my JSP page isn't working even though I have apache tomcat....